# Webservice expecting JSON, sending multipart-form data

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, web-services

I am trying to make the upload of files in a asyncronous way. I am currently using jquery.form plugin and using the ajaxSubmit method. Backend consists of getting this uploaded document and insert it into a document library. No problems in that part. Now when I try to do an upload, I get a 404 bad request error. The webservice expects JSON from a request. I noticed that this isn't the case, as in the request payload I get something like the following.

```
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Json45r11 (1).zip"
```

Whic isn't a JSON, so I think this is why I get a bad request.
Webservice definition of backend method is like this:

```
              [OperationContract]
              [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest , ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
              SuccessUpload uploadDoc(string id);
```

Front end submit looks like this:

```
      $('#form').ajaxSubmit({url: 'backend Method', type: 'post',data: JSON.stringify({id:1})});
```

Is there a workaround all this? Any help is appreciated, sorry if bad english not native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the webservice expects a JSON, in the declaration of your method just put that it receives an object of type STREAM.

this should work:

```
  [OperationContract]
    SuccessUpload uploadDoc2(Stream data);
```

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery.form plugin uses `multipart/form-data` encoded request when uploading a file which a classic ASMX web service cannot understand. You could replace your web service with a generic ASHX handler (`IHttpHandler`) which would allow you to handle any request format. Or even better if you don't want to get as low-level as handlers you could use some of the new frameworks such as ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET WEB API, WCF, ServiceStack, ... which all will happily handle `multipart/form-data` encoded requests.

Comment: the asp.net web api is very nice, first .net framework I actually enjoy developing services in

Comment: I would say the same for ServiceStack. I prefer it much better compared to ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: so I've heard, I foresee a little research project fun this evening